# function that may work in-place

Tags: c++

I have the following function:

```
shared_ptr_of_points filter(const shared_ptr_of_points input){
    shared_ptr_of_points result = make_new();
    for(const auto item:input->points){
         if(cond(item)){
            result->add_point(item);
         }
    }
    return result;
}
```

A typical use is:

```
auto filtered_points = filter(some_noisy_points);
```

However, it may be used in another way which is:

```
some_points = filter(some_points);
```

The above implementation works fine in this case. However, an unnecessary copy is done.

**The question:** What is the classical solution for this problem?

P.S. I need both cases to work fine where in the first one, the copy should happen (I have to accept the argument as `const`). In the second case, no copy should happen.

While overloading is OK, making two separated functions is not an option.

Comment: There's no silver bullet here, make a separate function that works inplace (which will probably boil down to `std::remove_if` and not much else).

Comment: *"While overloading is OK, making two separated functions is not an option."* - Just curious here, why isn't that an option?

Comment: Implement the "in place" version of the function. Now, write the version that takes a `const` parameter. It works by making a copy of the first parameter, then calling the "in place" version. That's "the classical solution for this problem".

Comment: @WhiZTiM actually it is a valid option. However, I did not want an answer that tells me to do two separated function (I think it is ugly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve your goal nicely by using a slightly different prototype:

```
void filter(const shared_ptr_of_points & input, shared_ptr_of_points & output)
```

If you are willing to use it, then a possible implementation will look like this:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

typedef std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>> shared_ptr_of_points;

bool cond(int x){
    return x > 100;
}

void filterCopy(const shared_ptr_of_points & input, shared_ptr_of_points & output){
    if (!output){
        output = std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>();
    }

    for(const auto item:*input){
        if(cond(item)){
            output->push_back(item);
        }
    }
}

void filterInplace(shared_ptr_of_points & inout){
    inout->erase(std::remove_if(inout->begin(), inout->end(), [](int x){return !cond(x);}), inout->end());
}

void filter(const shared_ptr_of_points & input, shared_ptr_of_points & output){
    if (output == input)
        filterInplace(output);
    else
        filterCopy(input, output);
}

int main()
{
    shared_ptr_of_points pts = std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>();
    pts->emplace_back(100);
    pts->emplace_back(200);
    pts->emplace_back(300);

    for(const auto item:*pts){
        std::cout << item << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "**********" << std::endl;

    shared_ptr_of_points resCopy;
    filter(pts, resCopy);
    for(const auto item:*resCopy){
        std::cout << item << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "**********" << std::endl;

    filter(pts, pts);
    for(const auto item:*pts){
        std::cout << item << std::endl;
    }
}
```